# Would these two queries provide the same result?

Tags: sql, database

Cities in countries that have a population above 20M (city and country are 2 different table)

Query #1:

```
SELECT name 
FROM city
WHERE country_id IN (SELECT country_id 
                     FROM country
                     WHERE population > 20000000);
```

Query #2:

```
 SELECT name 
 FROM city 
 JOIN country 
 WHERE country.population > 20000000;
```

Comment: The second query is missing an `on` clause

Comment: Why not simply try and see? Hands on experience is the best.

Comment: Yes got it! Actually, just a beginner, saw it in an example and was wondering. I don't have the tables made. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to be explicit on the join conditions

```
SELECT city.name
  FROM city
       JOIN country ON country. country_id = city.country_id
 WHERE country.population > 20000000
```

Note that, while the two query select the same data, but they are not "the same": one will probably be much faster than the other (depending on your actual data, indexes and what RDBMS you use).

---

Edit: in case you are figuring SQL out, it might be interesting to consider what the two query would do if `city` and `country` are swapped (ie: get the countries where city.population > some number)

Answer (score 2):

No, the two are not guaranteed to return the same results.  They probably do in your database, but you should use the version that you really want.

The `JOIN` version can return duplicate rows if `country_id` is duplicated in the table.

Further, you have not qualified column names, so you could get an error on `name` in the query with the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

As all I know about SQL, you should slightly change the 2nd query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM city 
INNER JOIN country ON city.country_id = country.country_id 
WHERE ...
```